# Getting error while debug the unit test in visual studio 2013 professional

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

Unable to start program 'c:\user........\UnitTest1.dll
This error I got while I was trying to debug the unit test in visual studio 2013 professional.

Answer (score 0):

In your project settings, change your Target Framework from "`.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`" to "`.NET Framework 4`".